# Doesn't java instance array need to be initialized array size?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code bellow. This is any abstract class with instance array queue. I never assign array size anywhere. But I can still use the array and can iterate to add data to the array. How is this possible?

```
public abstract class Operations {
    int queue[];
    int head;
    int tail;

    public abstract String enqueue(int value);
    public abstract String dequeue();
    public abstract String peek();
    public abstract String delete();
    public abstract boolean isEmpty();
    public abstract boolean isFull();
    public abstract void display();
}
```

Comment: "> But I can still use the array and can iterate to add data to the array" :

no you shouldn't be able to - it's a null field. 

Show some code of you using the class

Comment: Have you also ran the code? If the array is never initialised it is set to `null` and will throw a `NullPointerException` when used. This being an abstract class, can you also show an implementation of this class that is actually used?

Comment: This is another class that extends the abstract class https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YBpzvHv2W7/

Comment: And this is my Main class though it isn't completed yet. I just working with some portion. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xDyRb6VwMw/

Comment: @Asibul see my edited reply. Your code doesn't work, as expected

Comment: @Asibul : you can't - https://rextester.com/IUAP8237

Comment: This question doesn't bring any value to the community and should be removed. It shows that the author has no tense to debug and understand the code he writes... Also code tries to violate the language instead of to achieve a certain goal using the language... It's kinda "show off" attempt or something...

Comment: You should edit your question and include the code from the pastes in the question. Otherwise this makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified the variable `queue` just holds an address to the memory location of the beginning of the array or in this case `null` at the beginning

At some point in your code you assign a new array to it (otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`) using `new int[..]` which will then allocate the required memory and assign it to the variable.

Update:
I've executed OP's code and as expected get a `NullPointerException` when calling `enqueue`.

```
Choose option:
1. Enqueue
 2. Dequeue
 3. Peek
 4. Delete
 5. Exit
1
Enter a value to enqueue:
12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.Queue.isFull(Queue.java:16)
    at test.Queue.enqueue(Queue.java:50)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

Comment: But my question is without assigning size of the array how I can use the array?

Comment: @Asibul You are basically asking "how can I use an array without having an array?" You can't.

Comment: @Asibul you can't.  You can pass it around without looking at it, but the value being "stored" in that variable is null.

Comment: I know it's not possible. But my code is working. Can you please check my code once?

Main class: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RjgkBPsHgR/
Abstract class: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2nS6wT4KZK/
Extended class: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YBpzvHv2W7